# If the equation $(\frac {1}{\pi})^{|x|}=x^2-p$ possesses a solution, find the range for p.

Tags: functions

$$(\frac{1}{\pi})^{|x|}=x^2-p$$
$$|x|=\log _{\frac {1}{\pi}}(x^2-p)$$
$$|x|=\log _{\pi} (p-x^2)$$ Since $|x|$ is a positive value 
$$p-x^2\ge 1$$

I have  no idea on how to solve beyond this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite $p$ as a function of $x$,

$$p(x) = x^2 - \frac1{\pi^{|x|}}$$

and note that $p(-x) = p(x)$, an even function. So, we only need to examine $x\ge 0$.  Evaluate $p'(x)$ for $x> 0$,

$$p'(x) = 2x + \frac{\ln\pi}{\pi^x}>0$$

That is $p(x)$ is strictly increasing over $x>0$. Therefore,
$$p(x) > p(0) = -1,\>\>\>\>\>p(x)<p(\infty) = \infty$$

Thus, for all real $x$, the range of $p$ is

$$p \in [-1,\infty)$$

Comment: What if it wasn’t an even function? What would be the procedure then?

Comment: @Aditya - Then, you need to examine the whole domain $(-\infty , \infty)$

Comment: What did you achieve by calculating the derivative?

Comment: @Aditya - the function increases if its derivative is positive and decreases if negative, which helps to find its limits, or range

Answer (score 0):

The "range of $p$" in your question coincides with the set of values $p(x)$ taken by the function
$$p(x):=x^2-\pi^{-|x|}\qquad(-\infty<x<\infty)\ .$$
Sketch the graph of this function. Note that it is even, and that it is monotonically increasing when $x\geq0$.

Comment: I am not following you

Answer (score 0):

The equation is symmetric, concentrate only on $\pi^{-x}=x^2-p$ the falling exponential (for $x>0$) will be maximum at $x=0$ and its height is 1, it will  cut by the parabola if $p>-1$. So the $p>-1$. Then due to even-ness of the equation there will be two real roots.